# int c conflict with c == "\n" and c ==" "?

Tags: c

I am learning the 1.5.4 Word Counting chapter 1 of "C Programming Language, 2nd Edition"

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if ( c == "\n")
            ++nl;
        if ( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
            state =  OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
             ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

I intimate the codes line by line, but it report error when I tried to compile it,

```
$ cc word_counting.c 
word_counting.c:7:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
word_counting.c:15:16: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is
      unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
        if ( c == "\n")
               ^  ~~~~
word_counting.c:15:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'char *')
        if ( c == "\n")
```

I double-checked my codes, there's not difference with the original codes.

Comment: See how you don’t get an error from two lines down for the same comparison done right. See the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` is a character. `'\n'` is a character. `"\n"` is a string.
You can't compare character and string.

Correct code is

```
if ( c == '\n')
     ++nl;
```